# How to deal with skewness that is due to the specific sample?

Tags: multiple-regression, linear-model, skewness

For my master's thesis, I am performing regression analysis on my data, where *perceived performance* on a task was used as the DV (7-points scale, 7 being the highest perceived performance). The sample consists of college students (n>100) around the age of 20 and, as can be expected, their performance expectations are pretty high, such that all scores fall to the right of the distribution with a mean of about 5.5. There are 2 or three outliers on the low end of the scale but removing them doesn't change the distribution because the data is highly skewed to the left anyway. My questions:

1. How could I fix the distribution in order to perform a linear regression?
2. Since the specific skew is expected for this particular sample, can I just  leave the data as is?
3. what would be the implications, if I were to leave it as is?

Thanks a lot for your input.

Comment: Why do you want to "fix" the skewness? There's no particular assumption about the skewness of the marginal distribution of the DV.  If most of the distribution is focused into a few of the categories, I'd worry more about the discreteness.

Answer (score 1):

If your DV is a seven point scale, I'd say you probably shouldn't do linear regression at all; ordinal logistic regression is likely to be a better choice. OLS regression assumes a continuous DV.

However, you should also note that linear regression does not make assumptions about the distribution of the DV (other than it being continuous); the assumptions are about the errors, as estimated by the residuals.